# Wordpress: alphabetice posts using custom category template

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am trying to display posts ordered alphabetically by title, only for a certain category. I have tried to follow the instructions in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts) but I am confused because my code in the template pages looks quite different from the examples in the Codex.

I have a category named "designers" so I duplicated the category.php and named it category-designers.php. Inside, there is a call to a loop-designers.php

Inside the category-designers, I have tried the Codex pice of code:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$glossaryposts = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach( $glossaryposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post); 
    get_template_part('loop', 'designers');
endforeach;
```

But the output is weird: first it displays a list of posts ordered by date, then it displays the same posts but ordered alphabetically, only that the alphabetically ordered list is repeated as many times as posts are (9 in this case).

I know I must be doing something terribly wrong but can't find examples using the `get_template_part`, they all use a `foreach` just like in the Codex.

Thanks for your answers.

Edited: in my `loop-designers.php` I have basically the same as in the `loop.php`, but with modifications so for that category no date, tags or other info are shown. I pasted the HTML here http://jsfiddle.net/6qdvF/

Comment: Can you please show what you have in your `loop-designers.php` file?
I guess you have while loop in your `loop-designers.php` file.

Comment: @MangeshParte I have edited the post so you can see but yes, it's a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the piece of code you have there you are including a loop in a loop.  Using `get_posts()` with a foreach loop is essentially a WP loop, then you are including `get_template_part('loop', 'designers');` which is more than likely another loop.

You can remove `get_template_part('loop', 'designers');` from your piece of code and just stick in your tags to get the desired content, (i.e `the_content();` `the_title;` `the_excerpt;` etc..) or you can create a new loop with `wp_query()` like the below example.

```
<?php 
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>

    // put your content template tags here

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This loop will query "Posts" and category 1.  You can change `'post_type' => 'post',` to query other post types by changing the word `post` to the post type name.  Or change the category number to the desired category ID you wish to query.

Comment: ok what I did is remove the `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` inside my `loop-designers.php` template and replaced it with the query and loop from your example. It seems to work just fine! I guess I can change the 'orderby' value if I want to order them by date again?

Comment: If you remove that from your `loop-designers.php` it will affect any other pages using that template file.  Yes, you can change the "orderby" to date.  Read more about WP_query here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.